# Error while retrieving shape from database in jointjs

Tags: backbone.js, jointjs

I am able to retrieve all the shapes properly except [swimlane pool](https://www.edrawsoft.com/images/howitworks/bpmn-add-pool.png). I tried with jointjs 0.9.5 and also 0.9.3. Both of them throw similar error:

```
Uncaught Error: dia.ElementView: reference does not exists 
@ joint_0.9.5.js:5286

joint.dia.ElementView.joint.dia.CellView.extend.positionRelative    
@ joint_0.9.5.js:5286
```

Using jointjs 0.9.3 gives error at this line

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bbox' of undefined

```
if (ref) {
  // Get the bounding box of the reference element relative to the root `<g>` element.
    bbox = V(this.findBySelector(ref)[0]).bbox(false, this.el);
  }
```

My shape is defined like this:

```
joint.shapes.devs.Container = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend(_.extend({}, joint.plugins.TooledModelInterface, {
    markup:
            [
                '<g class="rotatable">',
                '<g class="scalable">',
                '<rect class="body"/>',
                '</g>',
                '<rect class="pool_header"/>',
                '<text class="t"/>',
                '<g class="inPorts"/>',
                '<g class="outPorts"/>',
                '<g class="moveTool"/>',
                '<g class="resizeTool"/>',
                '<g class="portsTool"/>',
                '</g>'
            ].join(''),
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'devs.TooledModel',
        position: {x: 200, y: 100},
        size: {width: 71, height: 625},
        attrs:
                {
                    '.body': {fill: '#ffffff', stroke: '#000000', width: 500, height: 200, 'pointer-events': 'stroke'},
                    '.pool_header': {fill: '#fff', stroke: '#000', width: 30, ref: '.body', 'ref-height': 1, 'pointer-events': 'visiblePainted'},
                    '.t': {transform: 'rotate(-90)', ref: '.pool_header', dx: '-0.1%', dy: '50%', 'x-alignment': 'middle', 'text-anchor': 'middle'},
                    rect: {stroke: '#000000', fill: '#EEEEEE', 'stroke-width': 2}, '.': {magnet: false},
                    '.inPorts circle': {type: 'input'},
                    '.outPorts circle': {type: 'output'},
                    '.port-body': {r: 3}
                }
    }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
}
```

**Update:**

I checked it so many times. This problem occurs only whlie retrieving from Database, jointjs is not able to get bounding box of the following:

```
console.log(V(this.findBySelector(ref)[0]).bbox(false, this.el));
```

I checked it manually and here is the error. Because of this error, the pool header is not displayed and the shape itself looks distorted

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because '.port-body' its not in your markup. So "*reference*" (port-body) doesnt exist in your **markup**

Try removing port-body, and all the references that are not in the markup.

Regards!